# Heathrow T3 to Euston Station

Tags: london

I land Heathrow T3 at 5:30 pm and need to rush to Euston Station to take the train which depart at 7:30pm. What would be the quickest route ? Heathrow Express to Paddington and Taxi to Euston station or ....
Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Which day of the week? If it is a weekday I would not go for a taxi, as it will still be traffic jam time, as far as I know.

Comment: 1 February Thursday

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. King's Cross and Euston are reasonably close together (half a mile / ten minutes' walk); however, there's a direct tube connection from Paddington to King's Cross, and not to Euston. So the answers could well be different.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Euston Square station is even closer to Euston than King's Cross is :)

Comment: @Muzer Ohhhh, Euston Square. I always forget Euston Square. Still, I think this should be a separate question. Especially since, without the advice to go to Euston Square, the asker might feel they have to take the Tube to Euston, which would add significant extra time. Also, the connection from King's Cross-St Pancras underground to King's Cross station is entirely indoors, whereas Euston Square to Euston station requires briefly navigating London's streets, right?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Oh, sorry, I'd misread your post. I thought you were just posting general advice, not giving reasoning why it's not a duplicate. I completely agree with you that it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Heathrow express](https://m.heathrowexpress.com/PurchaseTickets/TicketSelection) tickets are priced according to peak (7-10, 14-19 M-F) and off peak times. The off peak costs £22 for a single ticket. The tube also has peak/off-peak times/prices (6:30-9:30, 16-19 M-F).

You're cutting it very closely as you'll need time to leave to plane, (if applicable) go through customs, pick up your luggage, and then the ride to Paddington is about 15mins. I always buffer 45-60 mins if customs is included in a large international airport.

Depending on which line (Circle or Hammersmith) you take to Euston, the [underground takes 15-20 mins](https://www.google.ca/search?q=london%20tube&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari#fpstate=luta&ltdfid=0x48761ab2b05500a7:0x749d07ad72bbbe13) if you know exactly where you're going.

Another local may have a more direct route but as a past traveller taking Piccadilly directly to Euston (one tube station change) is about 50-60 mins. It appears that the Piccadilly line is currently affected by delays of [emergency repairs](https://www.google.ca/search?q=london%20tube&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari#fpstate=lut-st-leaf).

It should also be noted that you'll be [paying more £](https://www.londontoolkit.com/briefing/underground.htm) if you pay by cash a single way by tube instead of using an Oyster (contactless) card. That will also take a few minutes to set up and load.

It comes down to cost vs time.

Note that if you're unfamiliar, to add buffer to allow for turnarounds or asking for help.

**Edit:** As noted by other users: there is a bit of a walk from Euston Square to the station. Apologies, I was busy reminiscing on my time there that I forgot to note that the second link leads you to the underground webpage for travel directions.

Mdewey in comments below provided detailed directions for the walk from Euston Square to the station:

> When you through the ticket barrier at Euston Square turn right which takes you under Euston road and onto the correct side of the road (which is very busy).

Comment: @Stanley good luck and enjoy your trip!

Comment: If you have a contact less banking card, you can try that on the tube. It does not need to be an Oyster card.

Comment: Note that the Circle and Hammersmith and City lines go to Euston Square, not Euston, and this requires a short walk to Euston mainline station. If the asker tries to get to Euston by Tube, they'll have to change trains, which will take significantly longer.

Comment: When you go through the ticket barrier at Euston Square turn right which takes you under Euston Road and on to the correct side of the road (which is very busy).

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably hit rush hour in London, so a taxi might not be the quickest from Paddington to Euston.

Some years ago I had to get from Heathrow T5 to Euston in about two hours (I don't remember it exactly - and it was later in the day), I took Heathrow Express to Paddington, the Tube to Euston Square and walked from there, it's only a few minutes walk.

Comment: They are traveling PM not morning. Your route still looks good regardless.

Comment: Heathrow Express to Paddington then subsurface to Euston Square sounds like the quickest option. Feel free to add this to your answer, because it's really important: When looking for the tube at Paddington, ***follow the signs for the Hammersmith & City Line***. Your quickest way will probably be to use the bridge located towards the centre of the platform. The reason for this is that there are *two sets* of Circle Line platforms on opposite ends of the station; and the "Circle/District Line" platforms would require an extra change to get to Euston. Once at the Circle/Hammersmith & City...

Comment: ...platforms you can then use any eastbound train (Circle Line or Hammersmith & City Line) to reach Euston Square.

Comment: Probably I will take the tube from Paddington to Euston Square then walk to Euston train station.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that "pm".